# C# Conditions statement

Tags: c#, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm working on a conditional statement and I'm having difficulty getting my small transportation console application to run properly in Windows Studio 2022. After pressing 1 or 2 (Yes or No) my application goes back to my main menu instead of proceeding to the user choosing a route or choosing not to purchase a ticket.

```
 {
   Console.WriteLine("Would you like to buy a Ticket?\n");
   Console.WriteLine("Please Type 1 for: Yes");
   Console.WriteLine("Please Type 2 for: No");
   var response = Console.ReadLine();
   Console.WriteLine(response);
   int num = 1;
   if (num == 1)
   {
     Console.WriteLine("1) For the first route option, please type 1");
     Console.WriteLine("2) For the second route option, please type 2");
   }
   int num2 = 2;
   if (num2 == 2)
   {
     Console.WriteLine("No Ticket Purchased: Have a great day!");
   }
   else
   {
     Console.WriteLine("Your answer was not vaild");
   }
```

Comment: you only request input from the user once using `Console.Readline()`. You could use a `while` loop to request input multiple times

Comment: You aren't basing your conditions on the `response` input from the console. You're checking if num == 1, which is always true.

Comment: Where is the code checking the user’s response? The code asks for the user to type 1 or 2… but the code never checks what the user typed.

Comment: Take a read of [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and have a long chat with your rubber duck

Comment: Why not Y for 'Yes' and N for 'No'?

Comment: Consider using NuGet package [Spectre.Console](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Spectre.Console/0.44.1-preview.0.29) which has `AnsiConsole.Confirm` to ask yes/no question and `SelectionPrompt` to present multiple choices. Full [documentation](https://spectreconsole.net/) and [samples](https://github.com/spectreconsole/spectre.console).

Answer (score 1):

I'd expect your code to look something like this -- where you check the response value.

```
 {
   Console.WriteLine("Would you like to buy a Ticket?\n");
   Console.WriteLine("Please Type 1 for: Yes");
   Console.WriteLine("Please Type 2 for: No");
   var response = Console.ReadLine();
   Console.WriteLine(response);


   if (response == '1')
   {
      // do something to let them buy a ticket
   }
   else
     if (response == '2')
     {
        Console.WriteLine("No Ticket Purchased: Have a great day!");
     }
     else
     {
       Console.WriteLine("Your answer was not vaild");
     }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation. I'm brand new to C#. I went the route you are showing in your code originally and then I got turned around while watching some YouTube videos on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are reading the data in the variable called `response` and never using it.
2. You are setting the data in the variable `num1` with value **1** and `num2` with **2**, and you are checking them in the `if` condition.

You can try to create functions to execute within the if-else blocks to give you better readability over the code.

Answer (score 0):

First , the answers that I see in this page is correct.
it seems that you forgot the using of the response.
But I’m having trouble understanding your question.
You declare response as a var and then you decide to use int.
No problem, you can make it if you want.
But if you want to use int , you need to put it in try-catch block in order to avoid get an exception in case user will enter string.
This exception will get when you convert the var to int.
I add some comments to explain the code.
if you have questions - don't hesitate to ask.
goodluck !

```
private static void BuyTicket(bool retry = true)
    {
        int selection = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Would you like to buy a Ticket?\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Please Type 1 for: Yes");
        Console.WriteLine("Please Type 2 for: No");
        var response = Console.ReadLine();
        //for case user enter a string and not a number,  so need to give friendly message of the options available
        try
        {
            selection = int.Parse(response);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please choose '1' or '2' only");
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            if (retry == true)
            {
                //if the user will enter invalid data this time , it will skip and continue
                BuyTicket(false);
            }                
        }            
        if (selection == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You choosed to buy a ticket.");
            Console.WriteLine("1) For the first route option, please type 1");
            Console.WriteLine("2) For the second route option, please type 2");
            response = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Thanks for your choice. You choose " + int.Parse(response) + " route option");
        }
       
        else if (selection == 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No Ticket Purchased: Have a great day!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your answer was not vaild. Please enter '1' or '2' only");
        }
    }
```